# Find $\theta$ from X-Y coordinates from $(-1, -1)$ to $(1, 1)$ around $(0, 0)$

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

For coordinates from $X \in [-1,1]$, and $Y \in [-1,1]$, how do I find an angle around the origin?

I tried using $tan^{-1}$, but it has issues when $X$ is $0$.

How can I find the angle anywhere in the unit circle?

Comment: Both points lie on the line $y=x$. So it's a rotation of $180^{\circ}$.

Comment: X doesn't have to be the same as Y

Comment: In several common programming languages there is the `arctan2` (or `atan2`) function, which takes two arguments: the difference in $y$ and difference in $x$. This tends to be more versatile for exactly the situation you describe. `arctan2(1, 0)` returns `1.570796`.

Comment: what are the units of `1.570796`?

Comment: The units are RADIAN